# Convert Primitive dateTime to dateTime class

Tags: apex, soql, datetime

I am new in APEX and I am rapidly discovering the similarity to Java is skin-deep only.

I am returning an sobject `createDate` field in a SOQL query, and according to the docs, the field is of primitive type `dateTime`. However, I want to check the value falls within a certain range as specified by `dateTime` objects. If I could convert the primitive to an object that would be good.

But how can I do this?

ELABORATION - this is a unit test:

```
test.startTest();
Datetime start = Datetime.now();
// do lots of stuff 
Datetime finish = Datetime.now();
test.stopTest();

//verify results
Custom_Object__c co = [select createdDate from Custom_Object__c limit 1];
//somehow check that the created date is between start and finish
```

Comment: Can you elaborate again what you are looking to do/check with the CreatedDate field?

Comment: I have updated the question with more info

Comment: Not sure what docs you are reading, but an Apex [DateTime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) is an object . Apex doesn't use primitives i.e. there is an `Integer` type but no `int`.

Comment: Here's the doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/primitive_data_types.htm#i1435039 - it says that this type has a precision of 1 second, but the DateTime object has millisecond precision

Comment: @NickJ Yes the milliseconds are lost when a DateTime is stored in the database. But the same DateTime type is used. Unit tests are isolated from existing data (by default) so checking the CreatedDate is not necessary to write effective tests.

Comment: Are you using SeeAllData = true in your test class?

Comment: no, not using SeeAllData

Comment: It sounds like you might be fine without checking the times then. There won't be any data coming up in the query that wasn't created in the test. *in the entire execution context, not just between test.startTest() and stopTest()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this out -

```
    test.startTest();
    Datetime start = Datetime.now();
    // do lots of stuff 
    Datetime finish = Datetime.now();
    test.stopTest();

//verify results
Custom_Object__c co = [select createdDate from Custom_Object__c limit 1];
if(co.createdDate >= start && co.createdDate <= finish){
// if it comes inside loop, it means the created date is between the two datetimes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apex has built in syntactic sugar to allow what you want to be done like this:

```
System.assert(co.CreatedDate >= start && co.CreatedDate <= finish);
```

(i.e. it is not necessary to invoke [getTime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_getTime) to do the comparison).

Note however that DateTime database fields do not preserve milliseconds, so you would need to consider that in your test logic.